# Ignition OPC UA connection fail

Tags: plc, opc, ignition, scada-ignition

After a power outage, I had an error in the OPC-UA server on devices.

Connecting Error: hide Details
java.lang.Exception: Error during connect.
com.inductiveautomation.xopc.driver.api.AbstractIODelegatingDriver.connect(AbstractIODelegatingDriver.java:591) etc.

some ideas?

here some Tags with issues:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04HOV.png)

Comment: I think your question is off topic since this is only related to Inductive Automation Software. Please contact them for a solution or ask a question on their dedicated Forum (https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/)

Comment: In Inductive Automation they are a bit slow to answer my questions. but you are right, it's better to receive help from the source, also I was desperate for help at that moment hahah.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if any peolple need the answer, with support from In Inductive Automation we can found the posible problem is in the PLC's network and not from de Software Ignition.